# Posting a request to the new Fusion Table API v1.0 using VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-fusion-tables

We've been using the now depreciated Fusion Tables SQL API for a while to update our Google Fusion Table.  We created a VB.NET application that authenticates the request and performs the necessary task and have had no problems.  We're trying to migrate to the new v1.0 API and are running into multiple issues.

I'm able to retrieve an Authorization token but my problem lies in creating an HTTP Request to successfully authenticate and post a request.  In this example, I'm trying to create a new table:

```
    Dim auth As OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient) = GetAuthorization()
    Dim sURL As New StringBuilder
    Dim sRequest As New StringBuilder
    Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding()
    Dim data As Byte() = Nothing

    sURL.Append("https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables")

    sRequest.Append("{")
    sRequest.Append(" ""name"": ""Insects"",")
    sRequest.Append(" ""columns"": [")
    sRequest.Append("  {")
    sRequest.Append("   ""name"": ""Species"",")
    sRequest.Append("   ""type"": ""STRING""")
    sRequest.Append("  },")
    sRequest.Append("  {")
    sRequest.Append("   ""name"": ""Elevation"",")
    sRequest.Append("   ""type"": ""NUMBER""")
    sRequest.Append("  },")
    sRequest.Append("  {")
    sRequest.Append("   ""name"": ""Year"",")
    sRequest.Append("   ""type"": ""DATETIME""")
    sRequest.Append("  }")
    sRequest.Append(" ],")
    sRequest.Append(" ""description"": ""Insect Tracking Information."",")
    sRequest.Append(" ""isExportable"": true")
    sRequest.Append("}")

    ' Create the request
    data = encoding.GetBytes(sRequest.ToString)
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(sURL.ToString), HttpWebRequest)
    req.Method = "POST"
    req.ContentType = "application/json"
    req.ContentLength = data.Length

    ' Add the authentication header
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization: " & gCode)

    ' Send the body of the request
    Dim st As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
    st.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    st.Close()

    Try
        Dim res As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream())
        Dim sOutput As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
        Console.WriteLine(sOutput)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I get this error when I try to create an HttpWebResponse: "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."  I guess what I'm looking for is the code necessary to post an authenticated request to the API to insert/update/delete data.  Examples in C# are fine too.

I've looked into the Google APIs Client Library for .NET but I'm having trouble implementing that also.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999419/update-fusion-table-from-net/20086082#20086082